# Python NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python

i am inputting simple code into IDLE but it keeps telling me after I run the simple program that a word to check how many vowels is not defined.

```
def search4vowels(word):
    '''Return a boolean bassed on any vowels found.'''
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    return vowels.intersection(set(word))
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
        gal
    NameError: name '' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation? And you are not including all of your code. `gal` is not present in the code you've given here.

Comment: That error obviously didn't come from the code you posted.

Comment: when i run the code and input a word on the >>> such as "galaxy" "hitchhiker" etc, it'll say "galaxy" or "ga" is not defined

Answer (score 2):

I think you call your function like this:
`search4vowels(gal)`.

Try calling it like this: `search4vowels("gal")`.

You have to enclose strings in quotes, otherwise python is looking for a variable called `gal` (In your example).
`gal` is not defined==>Error

Comment: but that's an invalid syntax for def

Comment: I mean the call. Not the function definition.